# How many cups of batter does a cake mix make?

Tags: cake

I admit it, I'm lazy, I use cake mix 9/10 times I bake a cake.

There seems to be a standard size (because Duncan Hines, Betty Crocker, and our local brand all make the same size cake, same number of cupcakes, etc.).  How many cups of raw batter is this?

I'm trying to figure out what I need for a nonstandard-size pan I have.

Comment: It'd be easier to figure out if you remind us what size pan the mix calls for (at least for me).  Using standard pan conversion charts you can make up a ratio.

Comment: One cake mix fills two 9" rounds.  If I remembered how deep, I could just do the math :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A 9" round pan that is 1 1/2" deep takes 6 cups of batter, while one that is 2" deep takes 8.  That's for totally full to the brim.  This [source](http://cooksdream.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Store_Code=C&Screen=batter_data) says about the amount of batter from a box:

> An average 2-layer cake mix yields 4 to 5 1/2 cups of batter.

and should have a bunch of helpful guides to using batter for non-standard pans.